# Unable to read key/Value from Json using java script

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON from which i have to read the values which i was able to do succesfully using JSON.Parse.The problem is in one condition the key CurrentAddress is invalid when i test it in http://jsonlint.com/.So i plan to retrieve only this value and then delete it from JSON .I checked stack overflow and got the code to retrieve the value .But i am getting error
"Unable to get value of the property 'CurrentAddress': object is null or undefined.I know that object is null or undefined but when i see the code the object is getting populated with the below JSON details

```
{"CardDetails":{"NameEn":"HASSAN ",
"NameAr":"حسن سالم راشد البطاشي",
"CardID":"099778",
"CardType":"Citizen",
"CardExpiryDate":"25/11/2017",
"BirthDate":"19/08/1980",
"CountryBirthAr":"سلطنة عمان",
"TownOfBirthAr":"مسقط",
"NationalityEn":"OMANI",
"NationalityAr":"عماني",
"GenderEn":"Male",
"GenderAr":"ذكر",
"OccupationEn":"OFFICE CLERK - GENERAL",
"OccupationAr":"كاتب اداري / عام",
"SponsorNameEn":"",
"SponsorNameAr":"",
"PassportNo":"٠٢٣٦٦٢٠٣",
"PassportExpiryDate":"02/03/2019",
"PassportIssueDate":"03/03/2009",
"PassportCountry":"سلطنة عمان",
"VisaNo":"",
"VisaIssueDate":"",
"VisaExpiryDate":"",
"CurrentAddress":"
المزارع, قـريات
الصندوق البريدي 3168, الرمز البريدي 112",
"CSN":"21400052F296F",
"SAMCSN":"5900002163C73",
"ErrorDescription":""}}
```

My Javascript is:

```
        var jsonString = myAx1.readCardJSON();
        var a = jsonString["CardDetails"].CurrentAddress;
        alert(a);
```

I cannot use JSON.Parse in this case as  the currentaddress value is shown as invalid

Comment: myAx1.readCardJSON(); what does this method do ?

Comment: What is the check for its to become invalid?

Comment: This is provided by a Third Party and it returns the  JSON .I have checked the value and in variable jsonstring the JSON is populated.That method is working

Comment: @Ayan i dont know why but only in one case the data is invalid .I used a tool to check validity of json in http://jsonlint.com/ and found the current address is the issue.However i am not able to pinpoint what the issue in that is .I dont know arabic .I removed comma and numbers in this field and tried still the same issue

Comment: Please give us the result of `console.log(jsonString);`

Comment: There is a syntax error at `CurrentAddress` value `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: maybe you are trying to `alert()` the json response before the web request has been completed?

Comment: Well, JSON can't have newlines in it. CurrentAddress has newlines.. You could manually replace them with `jsonString.replace('\n','')`

Comment: @Akis I commented the alert messages but still the same result

Comment: @krishna removing the alert will not fix your problem, you just have to run it in the success event of the `readCardJSON()` method.

Comment: Manually replace `\n` with `\\n` and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code helps in removing the \n

var myJSONString= jsonString.replace(/[\n\r]/gi, '')